# onSharedPreferenceChanged() called on first launch only - is this an Android bug?

Tags: android, settings, preferences

**Background:**

In my Android app, I have a settings activity (type AppCompatActivity), which has three fragments (type PreferenceFragmentCompat) - fragmentMain, fragmentSub1 and fragmentSub2. The fragmentSub* are created when the user clicks on a preference in the fragmentMain.

When the app is started and the user navigates to these screens but *does not* change any setting, I do not expect *onSharedPreferenceChanged()* to be called on any of the fragments (since the user made no changes). And this is what happens - *normally*.

**Issue:**

While this is what happens normally, the **very first time the app is launched** (immediately after install), I am finding that when the user navigates to one of the FragmentSubs without changing any of the preferences, *onSharedPreferenceChanged()* is getting called (this is unexpected). This *does not* happen in the main fragment.

Not sure if this is relevant, but I am launching the fragmentSub* via:

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
     new fragmentSub1()).addToBackStack(*className*).commit();

Is this an Android bug?  Anyone else run into this?

It did cause an *exception* elsewhere in my code (*on first launch only*) - I was able to fix that easily, but did spend some time trying to figure it out.

I am initializing all three sets of preferences to default values on first launch.

===========================================================================
UPDATE ON July 22, 2018:

Finally figured out the issue.  I was initializing the defaults values for the settings as follows in the main activity:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.settings_main, false);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.settings_sub1, false);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.settings_sub2, false);
```

I had to change the third parameter in the second and third call above to true:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.settings_main, false);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.settings_sub1, true);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, R.xml.settings_sub2, true);
```

It seems if the method has the third parameter set to false, it will do nothing if it has been called before - even if it was called on a different set of preferences. It is just not smart enough.  This is also documented in the PreferenceManager Android documentation - quote: "*If false, this method sets the default values only if this method has never been called in the past*". I just didn't expect that that statement would apply irrespective of which set of preferences it was being called on.

Comment: Sounds like the initialization of defaults counts as changing the shared prefs, which makes sense because you're going from nothing to something.

Comment: That might have made sense, possibly.  But all of the shared preferences - on all three preference fragments - are getting initialized to default on first launch; however, only the preferences on the two (of the three) fragments are exhibiting this.

Comment: Finally figured out the issue. Since I could not add the solution in the comments section (too long) I have updated the question above with the solution.